# DD-WRT gateway separates switches into two zones

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have one DD-WRT wireless router acts in gateway mode connected to the internet via a cable modem.
The router has two LAN ports each connected to port 1 of a gigabit switch.
Here is a diagram

```
(Gateway Router) -- LAN 1 --------- Port 1 of Switch 1
                 |- LAN 2 --------- Port 1 of Switch 2
                 |- WLAN
```

I have two computers. Computer A with static IP 192.168.0.40 on Switch 1 Port 2. Computer B with dynamic IP 192.168.0.101 on Switch 2 Port 2. I cannot access Computer A from computer B despite them being on the same subnet.

If computer B connects to the WLAN, it can then talk to Computer A.

Should computer B always be able to talk to computer A? What settings am I setting by mistake that prevents this?

Comment: check your ddwrt settings under "setup->vlans", and make sure all LAN ports are on the same VLAN.